# Getting logcat of specific Android app on Windows

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm using the following command to get the logcat for a specific app

```
 adb -s ZY2243JGJ3 logcat | findstr com.android.chrome
```

But the command line just waits with no output. How can I get app specific logcat from a specific app on Windows?

Comment: can you try to use `grep` instead of `findstr`?

Comment: grep is not available on Windows